# Cannot read data from textfile

Tags: python

the idea is to write a python code reading data from a text file indicated below.

https://www.minorplanetcenter.net/iau/MPCORB/CometEls.txt

Further on, I would like to filter comet-data like name magnitude etc. etc.

Right now my problem is getting data output.

My code is:

```
import os.path

word_dict = {}

scriptpath = os.path.dirname(__file__)
filename = os.path.join(scriptpath, 'CometEls.txt','r')

for line in filename:
    line = line.strip()
    relation = line.split(' ')
    word_dict[relation[0]] = relation[0:20]


    while True:
        word = input('Comet name : ')
        if word in word_dict:
        print ('Comets in list :' , word_dict[word])
        print(filename) #show file location
    else:
        print( 'No comet data!')
        print(word_dict) #show data from dictionary
```

As you can see data in my dictionary isn't the comet-data.

[image]

It should be

[image]

Typing in "a"

[image]

Theoretically the code works, the problem is creating the dictionary?

Maybe I'm completely wrong, but it doesn't work neither with tuples or lists, or it's better to copy data into a .csv file?

Best regards

Comment: do `print(line)` in the for loop, you'll understand, you don't read the file, you're iterating on the filename string

Comment: fix the indentation in the code please

Comment: Thanx for your replies. I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

You saved the file path to the filename variable, but did not open the file for reading. You should open file, and then read it:

```
import os.path

word_dict = {}

scriptpath = os.path.dirname(__file__)
file_path = os.path.join(scriptpath, 'CometEls.txt')

with open(file_path, 'r') as commet_file:
    for line in commet_file:
        line = line.strip()
        relation = line.split(' ')
        word_dict[relation[0]] = relation[0:20]

while True:
    word = input('Comet name : ')
    if word in word_dict:
        print ('Comets in list :' , word_dict[word])
        print(file_path) 
    else:
        print('No comet data!')
        print(word_dict) #show data from dictionary
```

Also, your example has wrong margins near in `while` block, please check it.

Comment: Thanx for your reply. I'll check it

Comment: Do you want to print the file path on that line?
`print(filename)`? If you want to print file content, you shoud read it using readlines method and save it in a variable before.

Comment: No I put print(filename) in the code to get a output of the file location in IDLE, as well as print(word_dict) showing dictionary content

Comment: Ok, it should work as you expect.